# retrieve treeview data on double click

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

I am trying to retrieve `treeview` data by double-click(`row-activated` signal).
I have managed by now to do that by `changed` signal as:

```
self.view.get_selection().connect("changed", self.row_activated)
def row_activated(self, selection):
    (model, iter) = selection.get_selected()
    print(model[iter][:])
    return True
```

but I can't managed it with `row-activated`:

```
self.view.connect("row-activated", self.row_activated)
def row_activated(self):
    (model, iter) = self.view.get_selected()
    print(model[iter][:])
    return True
```

But, this is giving error:

```
TypeError: row_activated() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its odd to reply my own question, but I have managed to solve it as:

```
self.view.connect("row-activated", self.row_activated)
def row_activated(self, widget, row, col):
    model = widget.get_model()
    print(model[row][:])
    return True
```